# How to listen rest api continuously and send to last added data as notification in android?

Tags: android, rest, push-notification, notifications

How can I send a notification to the user when new data comes to the service by listening to the rest api by constantly listening to a service?

People said to use FCM, but how can I send the message from other api in FCM. What is the method of doing this other than FCM?

Answer (score 0):

You use FCM, or another technology like FCM.  You can't listen to a REST API continuously.  That's not how HTTP works.  You could do a web socket, but that will have problems around the device turning it's screen off and going into Doze, because your app which is listening isn't whitelisted for power. You need to use push messaging to an app on the phone which is whitelisted, which basically means FCM.

Comment: Ty for your answer, I am using an api that lists earthquake data. (It's not my own). I wanted to send it to the user as a push notification when new earthquake data came to this API. I need to listen to this. because the timing of the earthquake is not clear. @GabeSechan